# MYSQL Select last known row data by date

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, charts

I've been wrestling with this for a while now. I'm not sure MYSQL query is the best way to do this but I'm at a loss.

I have entries for certain people on certain dates, however they won't always be on the same date. Eg:

```
Person     Date        Product
Mike     2012/12/1      Pants
Chris    2012/12/4      Shoes
Mike     2012/12/4      Pants
Julian   2012/12/5      Hat
```

I am using this table for trending reports and I need to select a date range, example 2012/12/2 - 2012/12/10. I need a table that shows what each person was wearing each day so I can see what percentage is being worn on any given day. The output table would look something like this:

```
Person     Date        Product
Mike     2012/12/1      Pants
Mike     2012/12/2      Pants
Mike     2012/12/3      Pants
Chris    2012/12/4      Shoes
Mike     2012/12/4      Shoes
Julian   2012/12/5      Hat
Mike     2012/12/5      Shoes
Chris    2012/12/5      Shoes
Julian   2012/12/6      Hat
Mike     2012/12/6      Shoes
Chris    2012/12/6      Shoes
Julian   2012/12/7      Hat
Mike     2012/12/7      Shoes
Chris    2012/12/7      Shoes
```

And so forth.... depending on the date range. Ideally a table like this would be even better:

```
  Date         Product   Worn    Total
2012/12/1      Pants      1        1
2012/12/1      Shoes      0        1
2012/12/1      Hat        0        1
2012/12/2      Pants      1        1
2012/12/2      Shoes      0        1
2012/12/2      Hat        0        1
2012/12/3      Pants      1        1
2012/12/3      Shoes      0        1
2012/12/3      Hat        0        1
2012/12/4      Pants      0        2
2012/12/4      Shoes      2        2
2012/12/4      Hat        0        2
2012/12/4      Pants      0        3
2012/12/4      Shoes      2        3
2012/12/4      Hat        1        3
```

I'm currently working in PHP using a MySql DB. Any thoughts, suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: And what is the question? I can't understand how the title is related. Also, how should `Worn` and `Total` be calculated?

Comment: The question is how to build a query to get from my original table to one of the 2 output tables, if there is such a way. Worn would be how many of each product type are worn on a given day, and total is how many of all product types are worn on a given day.

Comment: It relates to the title because it needs to 'fill in' a row with data from a previous date if there is none for the current date.

Comment: Are you looking for a report/query or an actual new table? Does "worn" relate to an item type (hat) that was worn that day and the total is the total amount of items of that type (hat) that have been worn up to that day in the timeframe?

Comment: I am looking for a report/query. The usage stats are on a per day / per article basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudocode mostly:

```
for(EACH day in date range){
 $query = SELECT COUNT(product) from table WHERE date="day" AND product = "hat";
 $getResults=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults))
 {
  $inventory_count = $row['COUNT(product)'];

 }
 echo 'Date'. $date.' - 'Product: hat - total = '. $inventory_count;
 $query = SELECT COUNT(product) from table WHERE date="day" AND product = "pants";

 $getResults=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults))
 {
  $inventory_count = $row['COUNT(product)'];

 }
  echo 'Date'. $date.' - 'Product: pants' - 'total = '. $inventory_count;
 $query = SELECT COUNT(product) from table WHERE date="day" AND product = "shoes";

 $getResults=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults))
 {
  $inventory_count = $row['COUNT(product)'];

 } 
 echo 'Date'. $date.' - 'Product: shoes' - 'total = '. $inventory_count;
}
```

It's probably not the most efficient way to get it but it should get you the data you need. Put in some TR's and TD's, wrap it in a table and you should have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If Date is a mysql date field the first table would just be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date > start_range AND Date < end_range
```

where start_range and end_range are the date range you want in format YYYY/MM/DD.